# Why is >>= more often talked about than <=<?

Tags: haskell

Let's say we have `g :: a -> b`, and `f :: b -> c`. We can write:

1. `f . g :: a -> c`.

If our functions return monadic values (i.e. values in contexts), for example, `g1 :: (Monad m) => a -> m b` and `f1 :: (Monad m) => b -> m c`. We can write:

1. `f1 <=< g1 :: (Monad m) => a -> m c`.
2. `return x >>= g1 >>= f1`, where `x :: a`, to get a value back. Or even the lambda `\x -> return x >>= g1 >>= f1`.

It seems that `<=<` is more parallel to `.` in terms of syntax. `<=<` makes it easier to understand `Monad` is just about function composition that preserves context. Why is `>>=` more often talked about than `<=<`?

Comment: There is also a `>=>` function...

Comment: Furthermore I think the way you use `<=<` is more how one thinks about a functor. Not a monad per se.

Comment: This question amounts to "why not always program point-free?" but in the Kleisli category. I find it helpful to think about Kleisli categories. I am also glad that a computer can do nontrivial categorical plumbing for me if I help it by naming points.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think `>>=` and its cousins are just about composing functions that return values with contexts. Functor is the type class that allow us to put value in a context. Monad is the type class that allows us to compose these functions, while preserving the context. That's why a type constructor must be an instance of Functor before it can be made an instance of a Monad. That's what I think.

Comment: @pigworker Are there any good introductory materials to what you are talking about such as Kleisli category, points?

Comment: @Jonas Applicative is the one that lets you put a value into a context, not Functor. Functor lets you manipulate values within a context. Anyway, what you have described as "...just about composing..." is true, but it's one of many reasonable ways to think about monads. It's not necessarily The One Way.

Comment: @amalloy I think you are right that Applicative is the type class that puts a value in a context (with `pure`); and Functor is the type class that manipulates a value in a context (with `fmap`). So it seems that to a certain degree, Applicative is a more fundamental type class than Functor? Normally I just construe Applicative as the type class that allow me to apply 'values in contexts' to functions that don't expect 'values in contexts'; it sort of allows me to combine 'values in contexts' using normal functions.

Comment: with `>>=` the functions are naturally nested and it is easy(er) to refer to previous results: `... >>= (\r -> ... >>= (\q -> .... r ... q ...))`. With `>=>` we'd need to package up the argument `r` with the result `q` when passing it further down the line, `... >=> (\r-> ... return (r,q)) >=> (\(r,q) -> ...)`.

Comment: those names `r`, `q` are commonly referred to as "points": `return` (no explicit naming) = `(\r -> return r)` (naming the argument) -- also, https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/,  https://wiki.haskell.org/ ...

Comment: [1/2] @Jonas "So it seems that to a certain degree, Applicative is a more fundamental type class than Functor?" -- While "fundamental" can be a rather ambiguous word, I wouldn't put it that way, as `pure` is really an extra on the top of `Functor`. A key thing about `pure` is that it doesn't just put a value in a context, but it does so *without requiring any extra information*.

Comment: [2/2] @Jonas A good illustration of that is the pair `Functor`, `(,) a`. If you have an `y :: b` value, you can make an `(a, b)` pair out of it *as long as* you have some `x :: a` lying around that you can attach to it (`\y -> (x, y)`, or `(,) x` for short).  However, if `a` is a `Monoid`, there is an `instance Monoid a => Applicative ((,) a)`, and `pure y :: (a, b)` will produce a pair by pulling an `a` value out of thin air. (By "thin air", I actually mean the `mempty` from the `Monoid a` instance; in any case, the point is that you don't have to supply it explicitly.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`<=<` is a great way of explaining the [monad laws](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad_laws):

```
 f <=< return = f -- right identity
 return <=< g = g -- left identity
 f <=< (g <=< h) = (f <=< g) <=< h -- associativity
```

And it's very useful for demonstrating the category of Kleisli arrows:

```
 newtype Kleisli m a b = Kleisli { runKleisli :: a -> m b }
 instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where
   Kleisli f . Kleisli g = Kleisli (f <=< g)
   id = Kleisli return
```

And you'll see it show up in point-free programs. Personally, I'm also fond of its peer `=<<`.

But while it makes talking about the monad laws and composition easier, I think there's still some strong didactic reasons that `>>=` is preferred among monad tutorials and introductions to Haskell.

The first reason being that `<=<`'s strong suit is point-free code, and for the most part point-free code is harder for people coming from a language in the C-syntax family (C, C++, Java, Python, etc) to understand at first.

If "point-free" is an unfamiliar adjective to you, here's three implementations of the same function:

```
f a b = a + b * 2
f a = (a +) . (* 2)
f = flip (.) (*2) . (+)
```

They all run the same calculation, but the last is in what's called *point-free* style, where the variables on the left have been removed via [eta conversion](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion).

This example is very much a strawman, but point-free style is seductive and can easily lead to code that is very difficult for beginners to understand.

Another reason is that one of the near-universal questions beginners ask is
"how do I unwrap a `IO String` to get an `String`?" when first confronted with
Haskell's `IO` monad. The answer of course is, "you don't, you chain the rest
of the computation with `>>=`", `>>=` making it easy to explain the relationship
between

```
putStrLn "Your first name: " >>= \_ ->
getLine >>= \first ->
putStrLn "Your last name: " >>= \_ ->
getLine >>= \last ->
putStrLn ("Hello " ++ first ++ " " ++ last)
```

and

```
do
  putStrLn "Your first name: "
  first <- getLine
  putStrLn "Your last name: "
  last <- getLine
  putStrLn ("Hello " ++ first ++ " " ++ last)
```

One last reason, of course, is that `>>=` is in the definition of `Monad`, and
`<=<` isn't, and that's just the way the language is defined to be.  People are
more likely to talk about typeclass members than arbitrary functions when
teaching others about the typeclass, especially when the teacher is
relatively new to the subject themselves (as so many monad tutorial authors are).

Answer (score 1):

While `<=<` is more natural to reason about for many applications, there is actually a good practical reason for `>>=` being the primary function for the `Monad` class. The reason is that whenever you try to compose functions `f :: a -> m b` and `g :: b -> m c`, you always end up needing to unwrap the result of `f` somehow anyway, which is exactly what `>>=` does!

Compare for example the definitions for `Maybe`

```
m >>= f = case m of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just a -> f a

f >=> g = \a -> case f a of
    Nothing -> Nothing
    Just b -> g b
```

Try to give a simpler definition for `>=>`, it's really not possible!

In general, looking at the default definitions for `>>=` and `>=>`, we see:

```
(>>= f) = id >=> f
f >=> g = \a -> f a >>= g
-- equivalently = (>>= g) . (>>= f) . return
```

It seems that `>=>` is doing "more work" than `>>=`, so it is sensible to define a Monad using the simplest description of its behavior.

The theoretical way to think about this is that `\m -> m >>= f` is exactly `id >=> f`. What we're saying is that `>=>` is uniquely defined by its action on the identity.

(One might argue that `=<<` is better as it matches the normal direction of function application like `$`, `<$>` and `<*>` but it doesn't really matter)

Comment: With respect to `(=<<)` versus `(>>=)`, there is also the matter of sequencing effects: `(=<<)` sequences effects from right to left (it couldn't be otherwise), while `(<*>)` almost always sequences effects from left to right, like `(>>=)` (by convention).